# Solve an equation of order 3

Tags: calculus, functions

We have a function $f_{n}(x)=x^{3}+nx-1$  $n\in\mathbb{N\ast}$

I have to show that $f_{n}(x)=0$ have one solution $x_{n}\in \sqsupset 0,1\sqsubset $

i tried to take two different values $(a;b)$ and replace them by $x$ to have two 
different equation and prove that there's one solution but i couldnt go further .
Any hints ? or other solutions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $f_n(0)=-1$ and $f_n(1)=n$, it follows from the intermediate value theorem that $f_n(x)$ has at least one root in $(0,1)$.

On the other hand, since $f_n^{\prime}(x)=3x^2+n$ has no real roots, it follows from Rolle's theorem that $f_n(x)$ has at most one real root.

Comment: the first one is the best . thanks mate

Comment: If you want to show that $f_n$ has *exactly* one real root, then both parts are needed.

Comment: oh okay thats a new rule i have to write down  thank you

Answer (score 1):

While @carmichael561 has already showed there is at least one real root, I'm going to find it.  First, recall the triple angle formula for the hyperbolic-sine:

$$\sinh(3a)=4\sinh^3(a)+3\sinh(a)$$

let $a=\operatorname{arcsinh}(b)$,

$$\implies\sinh(3\operatorname{arcsinh}(b))=4b^3+3b$$

let $b=\frac12\sqrt{\frac3n}x$,

$$\begin{align}\implies\sinh\left(3\operatorname{arcsinh}\left(\frac12\sqrt{\frac3n}x\right)\right)&=4\left(\frac12\sqrt{\frac3n}x\right)^3+3\left(\frac12\sqrt{\frac3n}x\right)\\&=\frac12\sqrt{\frac{27}{n^3}}x^3+\frac32\sqrt{\frac3n}x\end{align}$$

Multiply both sides by $2\sqrt{\frac{n^3}{27}}$,

$$\implies2\sqrt{\frac{n^3}{27}}\sinh\left(3\operatorname{arcsinh}\left(\frac12\sqrt{\frac3n}x\right)\right)=x^3+nx$$

We basically want this equal to $1$ to find the root, thus,

$$2\sqrt{\frac{n^3}{27}}\sinh\left(3\operatorname{arcsinh}\left(\frac12\sqrt{\frac3n}x\right)\right)=1$$

Or, solving for $x$, we have

> $$x=2\sqrt{\frac n3}\sinh\left(\frac13\operatorname{arcsinh}\left(\frac12\sqrt{\frac{27}{n^3}}\right)\right)$$

Comment: i hope i dont have to solve x for an equation like this lol but thanks for ur efforts

Comment: @AymanErroutabi Haha, I actually found learning how to factor cubic polynomials a good waste of my summer break.

Comment: lol you never know when you will need it . maybe a maths competition when u got 1st prize u never know